# Error with adding string to 2d Array and displaying cout message (No error messages?)

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm new to this forum. Any **constructive** critisism regarding code, layout or anything else relevant would be very welcome!

The problem I'm having is regarding (as the title suggests) adding the `fullName` string to an array `seatArray` in your standard seat-reservation program.

The error I'm getting is that once compiled, there is no output after `'please enter your second name'`. No errors show up in the debugger when I compile. I am also assuming that this means nothing is being added to my Array `seatArray` so if you could at least point me in the right direction there I'd be grateful!

NB: All classes are separate header files

Firstly, my main.cpp file

```
// Main class - Scotia2
// Main cpp file
#include <iostream>
#include "menu.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{

Menu m;
m.userMenu();

return 0;
};
```

my `Menu` class (I'm not sure this is relevant to the problem, but I'll include it anyway)

```
// Menu class - Scotia2

#include <iostream>
#include "flight.h"

using namespace std;

class Menu
{
// Access specifier
public:

    int userMenu()
        {
            Flight f1;
            Booking b1;

            int option;

            cout << "Scotia Airlines\n";
            cout << "\n 1- Check Availability";
            cout << "\n 2- Book a Seat";
            cout << "\n 3- Cancel a Reservation";
            cout << "\n 4- Exit \n ";
            cout << "-------------------\n\n ";

            cin >> option;

            do{
                switch (option)
                {
                    case 1: f1.seatPlan();
                        break;

                    case 2: b1.addBooking();
                        break;

                    //case 3: c1.cancel; // Link to cancel.h
                        //break;

                    case 4: return (0);
                        break;
                }
              }while (option == 0); // End of do-while

                return option;
            cout << "\n";
        }// End of userMenu function
};// End of menu class
```

my `Flight` class:

```
// Flight Class - Scotia 2
// Contains information on seating (array), space available and return to menu option.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "booking.h"

using namespace std;

class Flight
{

public:

    public:
    struct Seat
        {
            int Available;
            string fullName;
        };// End of struct

// Structure for seat plan (24 spaces available)
    struct Seat seatArray[4][6];

    void seatPlan()
    {   //------
        cout << "Scotia Airlines Seating Plan\n";
        cout << "------------------------\n";
        cout << " 1D  2D  3D  4D  5D  6D\n";
        cout << " 1C  2C  3C  4C  5C  6C\n";
        cout << "                       \n";
        cout << " 1B  2B  3B  4B  5B  6B\n";
        cout << " 1A  2A  3A  4A  5A  6A\n";
        cout << "------------------------\n\n\n";
        //------
        for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            for (int j=0;j<6;j++)
                {
                if (seatArray[i][j].Available == 0)
                cout << seatArray[i][j].fullName;

                else
                cout << "Seating Plan is unavailable";
                }
        }// End of for loop
    }// End of seatPlan function

};// End of Flight class
```

And finally, my `Booking` class. This is, I'm assuming, where the error is occuring. I've tried laying my code out in different ways because i thought perhaps that things weren't executing in the right order. However this hasn't really worked.

```
//Booking class - Scotia Airlines
//This class will reserve a seat for passenger

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Booking{

    public:
    struct Seat
        {
            int Available;
            string fullName;
        };// End of struct

// Structure for seat plan (24 spaces available)
    struct Seat seatArray[4][6];

//variables for taking in customer details, calculating ticket cost (inc discounts) and adding details to system
    public:
    string fName, sName, busName, fullName;
    int age, livesAt;
    float discount, tickPrice, tCost;

    void addBooking()

    {
    cout << "\tBooking Menu \n\n";
    cout << "Please select ticket type: \n";
    cout << "1- Business \n";
    cout << "2- Western Isles \n";
    cout << "3- Ordinary \n";
    cin >> livesAt;

    // This will be used to calc total cost for each passenger dependant on ticket type
                    if(livesAt == 1)
                        {
                            discount = 0.75;
                            cout << "Please enter your business name\n";
                            cin >> busName;
                        }

                        else if (livesAt == 2)
                            {
                            discount = 0.90;
                            }

                        else
                            {
                            discount = 0.0;
                            }

    // Calculation - Standard ticket price is 60
                tickPrice = 60.0;
                tCost = (tickPrice * discount);

    //Create full name for pass to asign to seat
                fullName = fName + " " +sName;

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
     {
         for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
         {
             if(seatArray[i][j].Available == 1)
             {


                cout << "Please enter your first name \n";
                cin >> fName;
                cout << "Please enter your second name \n";
                cin >> sName;
                cin >> seatArray[i][j].fullName;
                seatArray[i][j].Available = 0;

             }// end of if
         }// end of nested for
     };//end of for

    // Message on screen for customer displaying cost of flight
        cout << "*******************************\n";
        cout << "\tBooking for " << fullName << " confirmed\n";
        cout << "\tTotal cost = " << tCost << " GBP.\n";

    }// End of addBooking function
};// End of Booking class
```

I'm aware the code may be a little sloppy (fairly novice programmer) so as i said, any tips etc are very welcome!#

Kind regards,

ZM

Comment: tl;dr, That's way too much code, try to make your example a [sscce](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: placing all of your code as inline is a very inefficient and bad practice. Learn to put your function code outside of your classes.

Comment: Is your problem that after you enter the second name and hit return, it asks you for another first name?

Comment: **Run this in a debugger.** I'm at a loss why you are asking for the first name, then last name, then *something* as a full-name with no prompt to the user indicating such input is required. Also, there is no break, so "a" booking requires 24 inputs?? fancy that.

Answer (score 0):

After your take the second name (`cin >> sName;`), you then prompt the user again with `cin >> seatArray[i][j].fullName;`. Did you mean to do the following instead?

```
cout << "Please enter your first name \n";
cin >> fName;
cout << "Please enter your second name \n";
cin >> sName;
fullName = = fName + " " + sName;
seatArray[i][j].fullName = fullName;
```

Also, once the second name has been entered, the loops will continue and a name will be prompted for the next available seat. You'll need to set a condition that breaks out of the two `for` loops once a seat has been booked. You can do that with something like:

```
bool booked = false;
for(int i = 0; i < 4 && !booked; i++)
{
  for(int j = 0; j < 6 && !booked; j++)
  {
    if(seatArray[i][j].Available == 1)
    {
      cout << "Please enter your first name \n";
      cin >> fName;
      cout << "Please enter your second name \n";
      cin >> sName;
      fullName = = fName + " " + sName;
      seatArray[i][j].fullName = fullName;
      booked = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I understand better now. Thanks! However now where my program should output the message at the bottom of the Booking file, it's not showing me fullName? It's just a blank space. Do you have any idea why this is? Thanks again, ZM.

Answer (score 0):

```
            cout << "Please enter your first name \n";
            cin >> fName;
            cout << "Please enter your second name \n";
            cin >> sName;
            cin >> seatArray[i][j].fullName;
```

This will:

- prompt for first name
- read a single whitespace-delimited string into the local variable fName
- prompt for a second name
- read a single whitespace-delimited string into the local variable sName
- read *another* whitespace-delimited string into `seatArray[i][j].fullName`

Any of those reads will wait for you to type something, so as soon as you enter a second name, it will silently go back to waiting for `fullName`.

You already have this code:

```
//Create full name for pass to asign to seat
fullName = fName + " " +sName;
```

but it's before the loop, when `fName` and `sName` haven't been assigned any values yet.

Answer (score 0):

After you answer "Please enter your second name", your program is still waiting for input:

```
cin >> seatArray[i][j].fullName;
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do with this line:

```
cin >> seatArray[i][j].fullName;
```

Why have the user input their fullname after they inputted first and last name already?  Or maybe i'm misunderstanding.  And as @ahenderson points out, just declare SeatPlan in your .h file and define the method in the .cc.  Otherwise it's inlined and that means it will duplicate the code wherever this .h file is included in the project.  Inefficient from a space point of view.  Typically its fine to inline very small functions, ones that only return something or do a very small calculation.

Comment: I (thought) it would put 'fullName' into the array?